# Game inventory database foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

just going through the process of setting up a database for a game im building.

It has 3 tables:

**user_table**

user_id - PK

username

password

email

level

location

**user_inventory**

user_inventory_id - PK

user_id - FK

game_item_id - FK

quantity

**game_items**

game_item_id - PK

item_name

now in my register script i simple insert a record into user_table saving the username, email and password, but since i made the other two tables and made the user_id and game_item_id foreign keys in the user_inventory table i am recieving this error:

> 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sik_game_db`.`user_table`, CONSTRAINT `user_table_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user_inventory` (`user_inventory_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)'

My tables are InnoDB, and they are all empty.

Here is the statement i am using to insert into the table:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO user_table (username, password, email)VALUES (:user, :pass, :em);";
    $args = array(
        ":user" => $m_username,
        ":pass" => $m_password,
        ":em" => $m_email
        );
```

So my questions:

1) is this the correct way to set up my database tables for an inventory system for a RPG type game?

2)Why am i receiving this error when trying to insert into the db?

**EDIT**
a SQL dump of my DB:

```
 SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";

--
-- Database: `sik_game_db`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `game_items` (
  `game_item_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `item_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`game_item_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_inventory` (
  `user_inventory_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `game_item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_inventory_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_table` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `level` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `location` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


--
-- Constraints for table `game_items`
--
ALTER TABLE `game_items`
 ADD CONSTRAINT `game_items_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`game_item_id`) REFERENCES `user_inventory` 
(`user_inventory_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table `user_table`
--
ALTER TABLE `user_table`
 ADD CONSTRAINT `user_table_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user_inventory` 
 (`user_inventory_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Thanks Tom

Comment: It looks like your foreign key constraints are setup backwards. i.e. there must be a user_inventory record with a User_ID before you can create a user_table. If you post the code you used to create the foreign key constraints that would help, or you can fix it yourself! :)

Comment: i set it up using the phpmyadmin ui, so i selected the user_table in PMA, and selected relationships then selected the user_inventory table in the list of tables and the same with the game_item_id. I hope this helps. I can post the SQL script that i can export from PMA?? Thanks

Comment: I have used PMA once, but I don't have access to it. either dump out the sql, or try create the link the other way around, and see if this solves your problem.

Comment: i have added a sql dump to my original post. i tried the other way but PMA wouldnt let me. thanks

Comment: both constraints look to be on the wrong tables. both should be on user_inventory, most likely the issue with PMA not letting you is either the fields you created to match do not have index's, or they do not match the type, since it works in the other direction most likely it is the index issue.

Comment: I thought that myself but I went with the flow of PMA. Both user_id and game_item_id are auto increment primary keys int(11) fields, so I can't see how it is a mismatch? Could you guide me a bit more please...

Comment: looking at the dump it isn't a mismatch, it is an index issue, both fields in user_inventory need an index in order to have constraints added to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I suspected, the Foreign Key constraints are the wrong way around.

You will need to recreate the constraints with the references the other way around.

Alternatively you should be able to run the code:

```
ALTER TABLE `user_table` DROP FOREIGN KEY `user_table_ibfk_1`;

ALTER TABLE `user_inventory`
ADD CONSTRAINT `user_table_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user_table` 
(`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Foreign Key constraints should be added to the table, where you want to ensure that any records added into that table, already exist in another table. So in your example. You want to make sure that when a record is added into the user_inventory table, there is already a record with the correct user_id in the user_table.

You will need to work out your logic for the other foreign key constraint to ensure that that one has been set on the correct table.

Comment: he also needs to add indexes to user_inventory.user_id and user_inventory.game_item_id or the above query will fail.

Comment: My understanding was indexes were created automatically these days in innodb when creating a foreign key constraint? But I haven't done it for so long, happy to be told I am wrong!

Comment: @WhyteWolf is this as simple as editing the user_inventory fields to be an index?? Thanks for your help guys

Comment: well have an index, but yes it is that simple, once the indexes are added you should be able to add the FK constraints in the proper direction.

Comment: apparently @Marryat i am the one mistaken about the index's. MySQL does create index now automatically. however i know PMA still forces the indexes to exist first. if the user was going purely off of queries instead of using a third party tool it would most likely work as expected.

Comment: Thanks guys, it all works splendidly now!, you learn something new everyday! Have a good one. Tom